# WCF SOAP suddenly switched to message contracts

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap, wsdl

I'm working on a WCF SOAP service that has suddenly switched to generating message contracts on every operation.  So, before, a method like string Foo(int bar) would be generated on the client side via wsdl with the same signature in the generated class, now it's generating the signature FooResponse Foo(FooRequest request).  It's unclear what change caused this, but we have dozens of methods in this service contract and it's not practical to decorate everything with [MessageContract(IsWrapped = false)], and I certainly shouldn't have to, since we were getting the auto-generated code we wanted before.  Is there another way to make this go back to working the way it did before?

Comment: Are you in control of the source code for the service and consumer?

Comment: The source code for the service and the source code for the consumer are managed by different teams at the same company.

Comment: In that case the safest thing to do is get the service team to publish the service and operation contract interfaces and service types assembly as a nuget package. Then the client team can consume the nuget package instead of a service reference. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is causing it but a solution would be to drop all your service references and just call the service directly via the runtime generated proxy returned from [ChannelFactory.CreateChannel()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms575250(v=vs.110).aspx).

Other than consuming a public web service, there is no reason to prefer the use of system generated service references over this method.

While ultimatelty deterministic, the code generation process behind service references is highly sensitive to starting conditions and adds another layer of stuff that can go wrong to your client application, as you have discovered.

Appreciate this does not address your problem directly.

Comment: I don't really want to get into a debate about the merits of strong, static types, but we prefer them and the system-generated service provides them for us.  And we prefer not having to code/maintain them manually.

Comment: @user7710 your comment does not make sense. Calling the service via a channel absolutely requires you to have access to the service and operation contract binaries - the only difference is that you are directly referencing them and not an inferred equivalent as you are when using a service reference. The very fact of using a service reference in fact removes you from the actual service types, by using system-generated code. My point is that you would not have had your problem at all if you dropped the service references and just called the service directly using a channel.

Answer (score 0):

I tracked down the change that caused the problem.  It's unclear why this caused the problem, but it did:

For reasons I won't get into, the consumer csproj is in a solution that contains another csproj we deliver to other teams in the company as a NuGet package.  The web service has that package installed.  Our consumer also had a project reference to the csproj that is delivered in that NuGet package.  Someone removed the project reference and re-installed it via NuGet instead.  For whatever reason, that caused the service reference generation to go haywire with message contracts.  Reverting it fixed the problem.